# Encoding error when importing->exporting Wordpress posts and attachments (images)

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding, export

I exported my blog's posts using the built-in Wordpress export tool. Then, I imported the posts on another Wordpress install with the attachments. However, when everything is done, all images that used to contain special characters (é,à,è) are broken on the new website. Here is what I figured:

Blog from which I export will be A, the one to which I import, B.

When I export from A, I lookup the created xml using notepad++ in UT8 without DOM. At the top of the file, I see encoding="UTF-8". If I search for an image containing the word 'flèche' what I see is an accent over the c instead of the e. However, if I copy paste it in here, it appears correctly as 'flèche'. Weird?

Moving on...When I import the xml to B, the new image that gets uploaded to B is called 'fleÌ€che.jpg' instead of 'flèche.jpg'.

On B, when I look at the broken image, it is trying to access 'flèche.jpg', which doesn't exist, only 'fleÌ€che.jpg'.

What can I do to fix this issue? A lot of images contain special chars so the manual way is not going to do it. I would have close to a thousand images to fix manually.

Thanks a lot

Comment: did u migrate the entire uploads folder?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded the upload folder to B. When importing to B from A using the built-in Wordpress tool, that's when a few files (the ones containing special characters) got renamed (flèche.jpg to fleÌ€che.jpg)